# laravel relation model -> belongsTo Model2 -> hasOne Model3

Tags: laravel, relation

I am missing a laravel relation or I just don't get it...
it is not hasOneThrough or belongsToThrough

The relation is as in the topic:

an Invoice (fkey customer_id) belongsTo Customer
that Customer hasOne BankData (fkey customer_id)

Am I missing an "eloquent way" for that relation? I could not find any answer to this ...
I'd like to query all Invoices with that customers bankdata with a relation

**edit**:
actually I was thinking way to complex ... I was working with Invoices and needed the customers bankData, without loading the whole customer, which I did not need. since both models do have the customer_id, a simple join did the trick

Comment: COuld you please just give the models so we can see what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I was thinking way to complex ... I was working with Invoices and needed the customers bankData, without loading the whole customer, which I did not need. since both models do have the customer_id, a simple join did the trick

Answer (score 0):

So
`$user->invoices` is a hasMany relation
`$user->bankData` is a hasOne relation

Both can and should be called separately because you don’t want to get the relation for every invoice being loaded, it’s not going trough the invoice model due there’s no related field in your table for the bankData model and thus cannot be taken from that relation.

Comment: actually I was thinking way to complex ... 
I was working with Invoices and needed the customers bankData, without loading the whole customer, which I did not need.
since both models do have the customer_id, a simple join did the trick.